# compare one column value with all the values of other column using pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the one excel file which contains the below values

[image]

I need to compare `a_id` value with all the value of `b_id` and if it matches i have to update the value of `a_flag` to `1` otherwise `0`.

For example take the first value in `a_tag` ie; `123` then compare all the values of `b_id(113,211,222,123)` . When it reaches to `123` in `b_id` we can see it matches. So we will update the value of `a_flag` as `1`.

Just like that take all the values of `a_id` and compare with all the values of `b_id`. So after everything done we will have value either `1` or `0` in `a_flag` column.

Once its done we will take the  first value of `b_id` then compare with all the value in `a_id` column and update `b_flag` column accordingly.

Finally i will have the below data.

[image]

I need to this using pandas because i am dealing with large collection of data. Below is my findings but it compare only with the first value of `b_id`. For example it compares `123`(`a_id` first value) with `113` only (`b_id` first value).

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.read_excel('system_data.xlsx')
df1['a_flag'] = (df3['a_id'] == df3['b_id']).astype(int)
```

Comment: `df.a_id.isin(df.b_id).astype(int)` will do your job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test membership:

```
df1['a_flag'] = df3['a_id'].isin(df3['b_id']).astype(int)
df1['b_flag'] = df3['b_id'].isin(df3['a_id']).astype(int)
```