# compare multiple column value together using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I know i can do like [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55790602/compare-one-column-value-with-all-the-values-of-other-column-using-pandas) if we are checking only two columns together.

```
df['flag'] = df['a_id'].isin(df['b_id'])
```

where `df` is a data frame, and `a_id` and `b_id` are two columns of the data frame. It will return `True` or `False` value based on the match. But i need to compare multiple columns together.

For example:  if there are `a_id , a_region, a_ip, b_id, b_region and b_ip` columns. I want to compare like below,

[image]

```
a_key = df['a_id'] + df['a_region] + df['a_ip']
b_key = df['b_id'] + df['b_region] + df['b_ip']

df['flag'] = a_key.isin(b_key)
```

Somehow the above code is always returning `False` value. The output should be like below,

[image]

First row flag will be True because there is a match.

`a_key` becomes `2a10`  this is match with last row of `b_key` `(2a10)`

Comment: can you add a small sample dataframe and expected dataframe(we will understand the requirement better) to replicate the question  thanks

Comment: @anky_91 : I have edited the code as per your comments..

Comment: iirc， it should be `a_key.isin(b_key.values)`. please try it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were going in the right direction, just use:

```
a_key = df['a_id'].astype(str) + df['a_region'] + df['a_ip'].astype(str)
b_key = df['b_id'].astype(str) + df['b_region'] + df['b_ip'].astype(str)

a_key.isin(b_key)
```

Mine is giving below results:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isin` with `DataFrame` as value, but as per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

> If values is a DataFrame, then both the index and column labels must
>   match

So this should work:

```
# Removing the prefixes from column names
df_a = df[['a_id', 'a_region', 'a_ip']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[2:])
df_b = df[['b_id', 'b_region', 'b_ip']].rename(columns=lambda x: x[2:])

# Find rows where all values are in the other
matched = df_a.isin(df_b).all(axis=1)

# Get actual rows with boolean indexing
df_a.loc[matched]

# ... or add boolean flag to dataframe
df['flag'] = matched
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and testing for [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) values:

```
df_merged = df.merge(df,
                     left_on=['a_id', 'a_region', 'a_ip'],
                     right_on=['b_id', 'b_region', 'b_ip'],
                     suffixes=('', '_y'))

df['flag'] = pd.concat([df, df_merged[df.columns]]).duplicated(keep=False)[:len(df)].values
```

[out]

```
    a_id a_region    a_ip     b_id b_region   b_ip   flag
0      2        a      10  3222222    sssss  22222   True
1  22222    bcccc   10000    43333    ddddd  11111  False
2  33333    acccc  120000        2        a     10  False
```